# Selecting specific data (td) from table

Tags: jquery

I need to select all the languages from the following table. The output should be Java, Ruby, Smalltalk, C++. What jQuery statement should I use? Thanks

```
<table id="languages" border="0" cellspacing="1">


<thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Language</th>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Invented</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Java</td>
      <td>Static</td>
      <td>1995</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ruby</td>
      <td>Dynamic</td>
      <td>1993</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Smalltalk</td>
      <td>Dynamic</td>
      <td>1972</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>C++</td>
      <td>Static</td>
      <td>1983</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This is part of an exercise for a class. We enter a selector in a textbox and then run the jQuery. We are allowed to use all resources, so I am not cheating. It's to prepare us for a final project. I enter #languages td:first-child and it selects the correct columns. When I try $("#languages td:first-child").text() or #languages td:first-child.text() the jQuery does not show results. All of the below answers should work. I do not know why I cannot get it to run entered in the textbox. This is probably not enough information to get an answer. You might need to look at the code for the textbox.

Comment: Thanks for all of the answers. They will be helpful in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map` method:

```
var lang = $('#languages td:first-child').map(function(){
       return this.innerHTML
}).get()
```

`lang` is an array of values(*languages*), in case that you want to store the values as a string you can use `join` method:

```
lang = lang.join(', ');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hZqHc/

Answer (score 0):

```
var langs = '';    
$.each($('#languages tbody tr'), function(){
       langs += $(this).find('td:eq(0)').html() + ', ';
    });
langs = langs.substring(0, langs.length - 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will add each value to an array:

```
​var langs = [];
$('#languages tbody tr').each(function(){
    langs.push($(this).find('td:first').text()); 
});​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
console.log(langs);
```

You could just as easily append them to a string.
​
See http://jsfiddle.net/fXdkg/ for a working snippet.